# How to change NOW() timezone

Tags: php, mysql, timezone, prepared-statement

I'm using NOW() in sql query. I want to change it to another timezone. is that possible?

Tried this function

```
class common {

    public function getTime() {
        $date = new DateTime();
        $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Paris'));
        return $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    }

}
```

And getting following error

```
Catchable fatal error:  Object of class common could not be converted to string in line below

        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO `items` 
      (`refno`, `color`, `size`, `qt`, `stackno`, `notes`, `price`, `add_date`)
      VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, $this->common->getTime())") or die($db->error);
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: MySQL's date functions don't do timezones directly, but you can tell the server which timezone to use: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is actually a PHP error, not an SQL error.  Trying to evaluate complex variable expansion expressions inside string interpolation doesn't work the way you're doing it.

Try putting the object inside `{}` braces:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO `items` 
      (`refno`, `color`, `size`, `qt`, `stackno`, `notes`, `price`, `add_date`)
      VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, {$this->common->getTime()})") or die($db->error);
```

See the subheading **Complex (curly) syntax** in manual page http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

---

Re your comment:

> now getting this error on the same line: Trying to get property of non-object

You haven't shown how you are setting `$this->common`.  Given the syntax you've shown, common needs to be an object instance of your class `common`.  I'm guessing you're trying to call the getTime() function without instantiating the class.  If you want to use static methods of a class, you'll have to do it this way:

```
class common {

    public static function getTime() {
        $date = new DateTime();
        $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Paris'));
        return $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    }

}

$stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO `items` 
      (`refno`, `color`, `size`, `qt`, `stackno`, `notes`, `price`, `add_date`)
      VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, " . common::getTime() . ")") or die($db->error);
```

If you are unfamiliar with the difference between classes and objects, and the uses of `static`, then you need to do some reading, e.g. [Object-Oriented PHP](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1593270771).

Comment: now getting this error on the same line: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: @epic, `common` probably isn't instantiated. Maybe you meant for `getTime()` to be static so you could call it like `common::getTime()`?

Comment: Thanks @MarcusAdams!  Now I need a new goal.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You would use this sql call.

```
SET time_zone = timezone;
```

Per the mysql documentation.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html